# Android tools replace issue

Tags: android, xml

I have downloaded a library that his it's own manifest.xml file which is causing me problems.

There is a line in the library manifest page that reads as follows

```
android:name=".controllers.NetworkController"
```

If I delete this line my program runs but I do not know what this line is for so I would prefer not to delete it.

I understand that I am supposed to add a tools replace to fix this issue, from my understanding the tools replace is supposed to go into my app's manifest page.

So I tried adding this line to the top of the page

```
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
```

and then try adding a tools:replace command to the  section but I am unsure of what to put there I tried a few things but none of them worked.

The error I received is

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

- What went wrong:
  Execution failed for task ':app:processDebugManifest'.

  > Manifest merger failed : Attribute application@name value=(com.app.appapp.utility.appfile) from AndroidManifest.xml:37:9-43
  >   is also present at [appfile:adyenpaysdk:unspecified] AndroidManifest.xml:12:9-75 value=(adyen.com.adyenpaysdk.controllers.NetworkController).
  >   Suggestion: add 'tools:replace="android:name"' to  element at AndroidManifest.xml:35:5-215:19 to override.

Comment: What error do you get?

Comment: Check my answer, I'm pretty sure it will solve your problem. I solved a similar one with it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In you manifest, inside the application section (where you have you app name, icon, label, theme), instead of tools:replace, add:

```
tools:node="replace"
```

For your google maps issue you also need to add to your manifest, inside the application section as well the following

```
<meta-data
        android:name="com.google.android.maps.v2.API_KEY"
        android:value="YourGeneratedKey" />
```

Comment: So I tried this and it is compiling now, however when the app starts it immediatley crashes?  Any ideas why this would be?

Comment: Well, it is probably some other problem in your application. Have you checked the logcat to tell what happened?

Comment: When I delete your line as well as the other line then the app doesnt crash.

This is the crash reason

Fatal Exception: java.lang.IllegalStateException: A required meta-data tag in your app's AndroidManifest.xml does not exist.  You must have the following declaration within the <application> element:     <meta-data android:name="com.google.android.gms.version" android:value="@integer/google_play_services_version" />

Comment: i am going to upvote you because it is compiling and when i get it to stop crashing I will give you green tick as well :)

Comment: Already got that metatag, also why would that only crash when i add the replace thing?

Comment: okay got it to work just added this

<meta-data android:name="com.google.android.gms.version"
      android:value="@integer/google_play_services_version" />

Any idea why the line you added would need that?

Thanks for all your help

Comment: I didn't have that issue so can't really tell. I'm glad you got your problem fixed